# Redshift - Checking different rows of same order and adding a flag

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have an SQL query that pulls data as below:

```
select order_no,pickup_city from sales;

order_no,pickup_city
1,city_a
1,city_a
2,city_b
2,city_c
```

Expected output:

```
order_no,pickup_city,Flag
1,city_a,Same_City
1,city_a,Same_City
2,city_b,Different_City
2,city_c,Different_City
```

In the above case, if the same order_no has two same cities then need to add a column "Same_City" else need to add "Different_City".

Could anyone assist how I could do this for the above sample data? Thanks. Using Redshift DB.

Comment: What database engine?
Generally you can do it: 1. adding column with row number (different way in different db), 2. self joing data from 1. selecting current row witch previous (using column generated in 1), 3. comparing current city and next.

Comment: What output do you want if an order has only one city? What if it has `city_a`, `city_a`, `city_b` (some same, some different)? Why do you want duplicate rows shown (eg `1,city_a,Same_City` is shown twice)?